# Should we use constexpr everywhere we can?

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++11

We obviously can't make everything `constexpr`. And if we don't make anything `constexpr`, well, there won't be any big problems. Lots of code have been written without it so far.

But is it a good idea to slap `constexpr` in anything that can possibly have it? Is there any potential problem with this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It won't bother the compiler. The compiler will (or should anyway) give you a diagnostic when/if you use it on code that doesn't fit the requirements of a `constexpr`.

At the same time, I'd be a bit hesitant to just slap it on there because you could. Even though it doesn't/won't bother the *compiler*, your primary audience is other *people* reading the code. At least IMO, you should use `constexpr` to convey a fairly specific meaning to them, and just slapping it on other expressions because you can will be misleading. I think it would be fair for a reader to wonder what was going on with a function that's marked as a `constexpr`, but only used as a normal run-time function.

At the same time, if you have a function that you honestly *expect* to use at compile time, and you just haven't used it that way *yet*, marking it as `constexpr` might make considerably more sense.

Comment: Wait, so this is a property the compiler can derive for itself?  Then why have the keyword at all?

Comment: @Nemo The compiler is required to issue a diagnostic when you incorrectly declare something `constexpr` that doesn't fulfill all the requirements. So the keyword is *at least* useful for the writers to positively assert that the declared function or constructor fulfill those requirements. I let the other issue open (to implicitly allow things not marked `constexpr` in constant contexts if the compiler can deal with it).

Comment: @Luc: So it is just a compile-time assertion?  Seems like they could have implemented that without stealing an entire keyword.  But OK.

Comment: @Nemo It's like the requirement that the size of an array be a constant expression. A compiler can 'figure' out `int i = 1; char array[i];` fine but we don't allow it. (Actually a lousy example because `const int i = expr;` is perfectly representative of what you suggest where the array declaration is only correct in some cases ;)

Comment: Yes, it's something the compiler *could* derive for itself. I seem to recall some discussion suggesting that it should, but can't find it at the moment. In any case, that didn't make it into the standard, so it doesn't matter much.

Comment: @Nemo: The compiler could figure out whether or not a function was `constexpr` itself, and I think it should've. Perhaps this was to prevent feature creep in specification where different compilers would allow different complexities of function to be implicitly `constexpr`.

Comment: @Nemo: `constexpr` expressions/functions are allowed only a subset of C++, for example there are no loops, only recursion. You may only call other `constexpr` functions etc., therefore calling `extern` functions is disallowed, too. This makes it trivial for the compiler to do the assertations. And of course this also is a kind of in-language documentation that fellow programmers and users will see. Basically, many of the arguments behind const member functions and const correctness in general also hold true for `constexpr` (although these are different topics except for the term "const")

Answer (score 10):

Why I don't bother to try and put `constexpr` at every opportunity in list form, and in no particular order:

- I don't write one-liner functions that often
- when I write a one-liner it usually delegates to a non-constexpr function (e.g. `std::get` has come up several times recently)
- the types they operate on aren't always literal types; yes, references are literal types, but if the referred type is not literal itself I can't really have any instance at compile-time anyway
- the type they return aren't always literal
- they simply are not all useful or even meaningful at compile-time in terms of their semantics
- I like separating implementation from declaration

Constexpr functions have so many restrictions that they are a niche for special use only. Not an optimization, or a desirable super-set of functions in general. When I *do* write one, it's often because a metafunction or a regular function alone wouldn't have cut it and I have a special mindset for it. Constexpr functions don't *taste* like other functions.

I don't have a particular opinion or advice on `constexpr` constructors because I'm not sure I can fully wrap my mind around them and user-defined literals aren't yet available.

Comment: It is worth noting that one-liner function restriction is removed after C++14.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to agree with Scott Meyers on this (as for most things): "Use `constexpr` whenever possible" (from Item 15 of *Effective Modern C++*), particularly if you are providing an API for others to use. It can be really disappointing when you wish to perform a compile-time initialization using a function, but can't because the library did not declare it `constexpr`. Furthermore, all classes and functions are part of an API, whether used by the world or just your team. So use it whenever you can, to widen its scope of usage.

```
// Free cup of coffee to the API author, for using constexpr
// on Rect3 ctor, Point3 ctor, and Point3::operator*
constexpr Rect3 IdealSensorBounds = Rect3(Point3::Zero, MaxSensorRange * 0.8);
```

That said, `constexpr` is part of the interface, so if the interface does not naturally fit something that can be `constexpr`, don't commit to it, lest you have to break the API later. That is, don't commit `constexpr` to the interface just because the current, only implementation can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. I believe putting such `const`ness is always a good practice wherever you can. For example in your `class` if a given method is not modifying any member then you always tend to put a `const` keyword in the end.

Apart from the language aspect, mentioning `const`ness is also a good indication to the future programmer / reviewer that the expression is having const-ness within that region. It relates to good coding practice and adds to readability also. e.g. (from @Luc)

```
constexpr int& f(int& i) { return get(i); }
```

Now putting `constexpr` suggests that `get()` must also be a `constexpr`.

I don't see any problem or implication due `constexpr`.

**Edit**: There is an added advantage of `constexpr` is that you can use them as `template` argument in some situations.

Comment: `constexpr` is completely orthogonal to immutability when applied to functions, consider: `constexpr int& f(int& i) { return i; }`, it's perfectly fine to use it as `++f(some_int)`. `constexpr int i;` is however indeed immutable.