# Is there a way to detect functions that could be marked `constexpr`?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Given I want to improve my C++ code base. One step would be to mark functions as `constexpr` which fulfill the requirements of the used C++ standard. Is there a way to determine whether a function could be marked `constexpr`?

The only way I came up with is to add `constexpr` to a single instance, run the compiler, and check if it complains that it is not `constexpr`. Repeat until all instances are checked. This approach does not scale.

Related: [Should we use constexpr everywhere we can?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785290/should-we-use-constexpr-everywhere-we-can)

Comment: Why only one at a time? Clang is happy to check multiple functions and report multiple errors. I just tested, and it did a hundred with `-ferror_limit=100` (default was 20).

Comment: Since labeling a function `constexpr` is an indication the function will, or is likely, to be used at compile time, it can be extra noise to label everything possible `constexpr`.

Comment: rules/restriction about `constexpr` depends of standard. but most rules can be checked by clang tooling. I don't think there is an existing rule though.

Comment: You could always automate it by writing a script that modifies an instance, runs the compiler to check.   It may not scale but it would only need to be done once on your code base - and only subsequent edits would need to be checked again.

Comment: [Is is_constexpr possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299394/is-is-constexpr-possible-in-c11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++23, there are exactly two requirements for a constexpr function:

- It is not a coroutine;
- If it is a constructor or destructor, its class has no virtual base classes.

I would not be surprised if every single function in your code base satisfied this.

So you can mark every templated and inline function `constexpr`. Because `constexpr` functions are implicitly `inline`, you can't do this to `extern` functions.
This should mean every function definition in a header file can be `constexpr`.

(If you have compiler errors for constexpr functions that could never produce a constant expression, upgrade your compiler)

Comment: this doesn't seem right. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @bolov <https://wg21.link/p2448r2> <https://wg21.link/dcl.constexpr#note-5>

Comment: "_I would not be surprised if every single function in your code base satisfied this._": And if one doesn't, then the code is ill-formed with diagnostic required, so the compiler will tell you about ot without any unexpected behavior or compiler differences. (Well, except that you can test in C++ code whether an expression is a constant expression, which will be affected by adding `constexpr` and could therefore affect behavior in any way.)

Comment: This renders `constexpr` kind of useless? Same as `inline`, it does no longer transport any meaningful information anymore.

Comment: @usr1234567 `inline` completely changes the meaning of a function definition for the purpose of the ODR/linker. It can never be used or dropped arbitrarily. `constexpr` can influence program behavior if code tests whether expressions are constant expressions and it can increase compile times, because the compiler is forced to check more expressions for constant evaluation. It also implies `inline`, which as above has important meaning. So, it still has some meaning and probably won't be made implicit.

Answer (score 1):

As there are more and more relaxations for `constexpr`, it's easier to ask:

> Is there a way to detect functions that *shouldn't* be `constexpr`?

The following functions should not be `constexpr`:

1. functions with declaration/definition split between header/source

   - technically, you can make them `constexpr`, but they would be unusable in constant expressions without the definition being available
2. member functions of classes which have no `constexpr` constructor

   - technically, they can be `constexpr`, but this `constexpr` would be misleading
3. functions that never produce a constant expression (due to `throw`, `goto`, etc.)

   - even those can be marked `constexpr` since C++23, see [P2448: Relaxing some constexpr restrictions](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r2.html)
4. functions that aren't [constexpr-suitable](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#def:constexpr-suitable) even in C++23:

   - coroutines
   - constructors and destructors of classes with virtual base classes

Every other function (which in some code bases makes up the vast majority of functions) can be `constexpr`.
You could even automate this process using something like a clang-tidy rule.

#### Note on C++20

It's more complicated in C++20 and older standards because there is the following rule:

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a [core constant expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#def:expression,core_constant), or, for a constructor, an evaluated subexpression of the initialization full-expression of some [constant-initialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#def:constant-initialized) object, **the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required**.

- [C++20 [dcl.constexpr] p6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.constexpr#6)

This rule was dropped in the aforementioned proposal, but in C++20, it makes it harder to decide when to apply `constexpr`.
Proving automatically whether there exists a set of arguments that produces a constant expression is not easy.